# NodeJS: Error: Cannot find module '/models/filename' after having renamed it

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, visual-studio-code

I am still relatively new to NodeJS. Now I encounter this problem: I had a file called "`./models/route`" I renamed it by changing the filename in VS Code to: "`./models/routes`". I then changed that name in all of the scripts. I checked, doubledchecked, triplechecked and quadruplechecked that it has been changed everywhere and it has.

Now I get this error in the console:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './models/routes'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node-projects\wandelverhalen\controllers\routesController.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node-projects\wandelverhalen\index.js:11:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..
```

The error apparently is encountered in `internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638`. So it does not point me to a script that I made or can change.

I really am at a loss...

Edit:

As Mosifa points out in his comment the error points to `./wandelverhalen/controllers/routesController.js` and `./wandelverhalen/index.js`.

Here are the scripts. I still can't find the problem.

index.js:

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();

const Routes = require("./models/routes");

const homeController = require("./controllers/homeController");
// const errorController = require("./controllers/errorController");
const routesController = require("./controllers/routesController");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/db_wandelen", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
});

app
  .set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000)
  .set("view engine", "ejs")

  .use(
    express.urlencoded({
      extended: false
    })
  )
  .use(express.json())
  .use(express.static("static"))
  .use(layouts)
  .use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Request made to ${req.url}`);
    next();
  })
  // .use(errorController.pageNotFoundError)
  // .use(errorController.internalServerError)

  .get("/", homeController.start)
  .get("/kempen", homeController.kempen)
  .get("/rivieren", homeController.rivieren)
  .get("/oost_belgie", homeController.oost_belgie)

  .listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log(`Server running at port ${app.get("port")}`);
  });
```

routesController.js:

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Routes = require("./models/routes");

exports.getAllRoutes = (req, res, next) => {
  Routes.find({}, (error, routes) => {
    if (error) next(error);
    req.data = routes;
    next();
  });
};
```

Comment: That's weired and seem's to be impossible! The error points to `./wandelverhalen/controllers/routesController.js` and `./wandelverhalen/index.js`. Could you please check these files?!

Comment: Indeed. The solution is to add an extra dot in the path on line 4 in the `routesController.js` file. (`const Routes = require("../models/routes");
`) `index.js` is located in the root of the project. `routesController.js` is not,

Comment: NOTE: The fact that I renamed the file has nothing to do with the problem I faced.